# how to compare the value in textbox of mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two text boxes UserName and Password in a view, when click on the submit button I have to compare the username and password in the controller and give the access to the other view,

I am not using any database to pull up username and password, I am using this for example practice.

Comment: You should look in default template provided in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let your controller accept a model that is binded in your view - with UserName and Password properties. Then depending on your logic in the controller render the specific view.

You could take a look at the AccountController class in the ASP.Net MVC sample project, I'm pretty sure you'll get the right direction in solving this.

Hope this helps.